# XML Parsing in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have to parse XML,for that have used some code that's working but problem is not we have nested XML this code is unable to parse all data.So please suggest me how to part this.

**XML**

```
<Author>
  <Book id="101" name="Computer" subcategories="2">
    <Book id="600" name="java" subcategories="0" contents="10 books"/>
    <Book id="601" name="php" subcategories="0" contents="5 books"/>
  </Book>
  <Book id="201" name="Language" subcategories="2">
    <Book id="700" name="Hindi" subcategories="0" contents="6 books"/>
    <Book id="701" name="English" subcategories="0" contents="4 books"/>
  </Book>
  <Book id="301" name="Music" subcategories="2">
    <Book id="800" name="life" subcategories="0" contents="10 books"/>
    <Book id="801" name="Wild" subcategories="0" contents="5 books"/>
  </Book>
  <Book id="401" name="Story" subcategories="2">
    <Book id="900" name="My Life" subcategories="0" contents="1 books"/>
    <Book id="901" name="One Day" subcategories="0" contents="1 books"/>
  </Book>
</Author>
```

**Parser method:**

```
public void parser()
        {
            XElement nodes = XElement.Load("file.xml");

            var node = from nd in nodes.DescendantNodes() select nd;

            foreach (XElement nds in node)
            {
                string name = nds.Attribute("name").Value;
                int id=Convert.ToInt32(nds.Attribute("id").Value);
                MessageBox.Show("" + name);
                MessageBox.Show("" + id);
                if (nds.HasElements)
                {
                     getChild(nds.DescendantNodes(),id);
                }

            }
 public void getChild(IEnumerable<XNode> node,int id)
        {

            foreach (XElement nds in node)
            {


                IEnumerable<XNode> nd=from list in nds.DescendantNodes() select list;
                int temp = Convert.ToInt32(ids);



                    foreach (XElement ss in nd)
                    {
                        string name = ss.Attribute("name").Value;
                        MessageBox.Show("" + name);
                    }

                if (nds.HasElements)
                {
                    getChild(nds.DescendantNodes(),id);
                }
            }
        }
```

I have above XML and have used above code for parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Perhaps you're looking for this:**

```
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(@"<Author>
                                  <Book id=""101"" name=""Computer"" subcategories=""2"">
                                    <Book id=""600"" name=""java"" subcategories=""0"" contents=""10 books""/>
                                    <Book id=""601"" name=""php"" subcategories=""0"" contents=""5 books""/>
                                  </Book>
                                  <Book id=""201"" name=""Language"" subcategories=""2"">
                                    <Book id=""700"" name=""Hindi"" subcategories=""0"" contents=""6 books""/>
                                    <Book id=""701"" name=""English"" subcategories=""0"" contents=""4 books""/>
                                  </Book>
                                  <Book id=""301"" name=""Music"" subcategories=""2"">
                                    <Book id=""800"" name=""life"" subcategories=""0"" contents=""10 books""/>
                                    <Book id=""801"" name=""Wild"" subcategories=""0"" contents=""5 books""/>
                                  </Book>
                                  <Book id=""401"" name=""Story"" subcategories=""2"">
                                    <Book id=""900"" name=""My Life"" subcategories=""0"" contents=""1 books""/>
                                    <Book id=""901"" name=""One Day"" subcategories=""0"" contents=""1 books""/>
                                  </Book>
                                </Author>");
var query = doc.Descendants();
foreach(XElement ele in query){
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0}\nValue: {1}\n",ele.Name.LocalName.ToString(),ele));
    if (ele.HasAttributes){
        var query1 = ele.Attributes();
        foreach (XAttribute att in query1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Attribute: {0}\nValue: {1}\n", att.Name.LocalName.ToString(), att.Value));
        };
    };
};
```